# Cannot parse selected Object to int (JOptionPane)

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to get an integer from a JOptionPane selection from an Object.
Here is the code:

```
Object[] selectionValues = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};

String initialSelection = "";

Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Would you like to add an event?","July Planner", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, selectionValues, initialSelection);

int selection1 = Integer.parseInt(selection);
```

The problem that keeps appearing is with the final line

> cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : method parseInt(java.lang.Object)
>   location: class java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 1):

The `Integer.parseInt(...)` method takes a String parameter, and you're not passing in a String.

But regardless, there's no need to parse as you've already got an Integer selection, not a String. Get the value:

```
int value = ((Integer) selection).intValue();
```

Comment: @TimoSta: yes, I was checking the API after posting the question, and you're right.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the advantage of calling `intValue()` over just letting it AutoUnbox? Isn't `intValue()` actually called implicitly anyways?